# Why does shuffle not work in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have data from JSON object, each item contains a question and an answer, I need to set 2 state items: 1 is the original array, 1 is a shuffled array, then render them later.

However, both my `questions` and `answers` are the same even my shuffle function works.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.shuffleData = this.shuffleData.bind(this)
    this.state = {
        questions: [],
        answers: []
    }
}

shuffleData = data => {
    let i = data.length - 1
    while (i > 0) {
        const   j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1)),
                temp = data[i]
        data[i] = data[j]
        data[j] = temp
        i--
    }
    return data
}

componentDidMount() {
    API.getQuesitons()
    .then(res => {
        const   questions = res.data, // [{question: 'some question', answer: 'some answer'}, {}, ...]
                answers = this.shuffleData(questions)
        this.setState({questions, answers})

        console.log(this.state) // both questions and answers are the same
    })
}
```

for your convenience, I have a dummy JSON object here:

```
[
    {_id: '1', question: 'q1', answer: 'a1'},
    {_id: '2', question: 'q2', answer: 'a2'},
    {_id: '3', question: 'q3', answer: 'a3'},
    {_id: '4', question: 'q4', answer: 'a4'},
    {_id: '5', question: 'q5', answer: 'a5'},
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sending the array's reference to the shuffle function. By doing this you are modifying the original array, not a copy of it. So at the end you get just one array shuffled referenced by two vars.
Try changing this:
`answers = this.shuffleData(questions)`
For this:
`answers = this.shuffleData([...questions])`
This will clone your array before shuffling it.

Answer (score 1):

You are just doing an in-place shuffle of the question array.

Same array before and after

You could do something like:

```
const   questions = res.data, // [{question: 'some question', answer: 'some answer'}, {}, ...]
        answers = this.shuffleData([].concat(questions))
```

Also your shuffle is pretty poor. The reason being that at each index the chance of selecting the same random index is pretty high and as you go through the array the chance increases. e.g. at index 4 you have a 20% chance of swapping what is at index 4 with itself -ie. no change .At index 3 you have a 25% chance of no change. at 2 a 33% chance of no change. At 1 a 50% chance of no change and at 0 a 100% chance of no change.

A better approach would be to simply swap randomly:

```
for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()* (data.length));
    var tmp = data[i];
    data[i] = data[rand];
    data[rand] = tmp;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are shuffling the entire objects in your array, not the actual question/answer keys inside them. The following achieves what I think you want:

```
shuffleData = data => {
    let i = data.length - 1
    while (i > 0) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1)),
            temp = data[i].answer
        data[i].answer = data[j].answer
        data[j].answer = temp
        i--
        console.log(data)
    }
    return data
}

let myArr = [
    {_id: '1', question: 'q1', answer: 'a1'},
    {_id: '2', question: 'q2', answer: 'a2'},
    {_id: '3', question: 'q3', answer: 'a3'},
    {_id: '4', question: 'q4', answer: 'a4'},
    {_id: '5', question: 'q5', answer: 'a5'},
];

console.log(shuffleData(myArr));
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, that's not what I want. I need to keep the right answer for the question. Your solution shuffle the answers so the answer id doesn't match anymore. I only need to shuffle the order of each question-answer item in the array.

Comment: @Viet By any chance, are you looking for `componentWillUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate` instead of `componentDidMount`.

Comment: No, there's an answer that is what I was looking for. Thank you btw.